# Can NtReadFile() produce a short read without reaching eof?

Tags: winapi, driver, windows-kernel, nt-native-api

I was testing `NtReadFile()` function on my Win7 against NTFS volume and noticed that in following code (handle was opened with `FILE_SYNCHRONOUS_IO_NONALERT` flag):

```
IO_STATUS_BLOCK io;
NTSTATUS r = NtReadFile(h, NULL, NULL, NULL, &io, buf, buf_size, &pos, NULL);
```

`io.Information` (which supposed to contain number of bytes received) gets populated only if `r == STATUS_SUCCESS`. If `r == STATUS_END_OF_FILE` io.Information contains original garbage and (it seems) no data was read in that call.

So, can I assume if `r == STATUS_SUCCESS` and `io.Information < buf_size` -- we've reached end of file? Or should I keep calling `NtReadFile` until it returns `STATUS_END_OF_FILE`? (i.e. short read is possible).

On one hand Microsoft [claims](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/ntifs/nf-ntifs-ntreadfile) short reads aren't possible:

> NtReadFile ... terminates the read operation under one of the following conditions:
>
> - The buffer is full because the number of bytes specified by the Length parameter has been read. Therefore, no more data can be placed into the buffer without an overflow.
> - The end of file is reached during the read operation, so there is no more data in the file to be transferred into the buffer.

... and I would like to avoid unnecessary `NtReadFile` call. On the other hand, my experience suggests to never trust Microsoft 100%.

Comment: yes, if `io.Information < buf_size` end of file is reached during the read operation. and how you already noted - `IO_STATUS_BLOCK` is filled only if `!NT_ERROR(status)` returned

Comment: @RbMm Are you saying "short read" (reading less that requested and yet not reaching eof) is not possible?

Comment: it possible only if eof reached

Comment: your quote from documentation is correct and already answer on your question

Comment: @RbMm Thank you. Unfortunately this means if my file is 1kb and `buf_size == 1kb` -- I'll end up with two `NtReadFile` calls... :-\

Comment: you can at begin query file size for example for know exactly how many read. also possibility that you random read exactly until eof also low. not understand in what problem

Comment: it isn't a big problem -- just a nuisance